# Listen to a dynamic number of dojo widgets (dijits)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I need to dynamically generate a web page UI using Javascript and dojo. I need to listen to the generated widgets in order to react on user input, but I cannot determine which one was changed...

```
var combobox = new dijit.form.ComboBox(
{
    id: id,
    store: dataStore,
    onChange: dojo.hitch(this, this._comboChanged)
});
```

In the call to `_comboChanged` I get the new value, but I also need to know which combo was pressed. There can be any numbers of combos and currently I store them in an array after creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the combo box itself to the comboChanged method:

```
var combobox = new dijit.form.ComboBox(
{
  id: id,
  store: dataStore
});
combobox.onChange = dojo.hitch(this, this._comboChanged, combobox);
```